# Refactor link to show/hide a table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a table with row which cab be hidden by user. It's implemented this way:

Markup:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table style="margin-left: auto; text-align: right;">
            <tr>
               <td class="stats-hide">
                  <a href="#" onclick="hideStats();">Hide</a>
               </td>
               <td class="stats-show" style="display: none;">
                  <a href="#" onclick="showStats();">Show</a>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="stats-hide">
      <td>
        <!-- data -->
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

And jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function hideStats() {
        hideControls(true, $('.stats-hide'));
        hideControls(false, $('.stats-show'));
    }

    function showStats() {
        hideControls(false, $('.stats-hide'));
        hideControls(true, $('.stats-show'));
    }

    function hideControls(value, arr) {
        $(arr).each(function () {
            if (value) {
                $(this).hide();
            }
            else {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
 }
</script>
```

How to implement the same behavior with one, single link and one, probably, CSS class?

My idea - store somewhere a boolean variable and toggle controls visibility relatively to this variable. Are there more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the row hiding not working properly on IE? What is the version of jQuery and the browser which is troublesome?

I created an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/CqQdc/1/) using toggle as suggested by @Galen and it works on Chrome, Firefox, and Safari. I don't have access to IE.

Here's the code:

#### HTML

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <table class="data">
            <tr>
               <td class="stats-hide">
                  <a href="#" class="toggle-stats">Hide</a>
               </td>
               <td class="stats-show">
                  <a href="#" class="toggle-stats">Show</a>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </table>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="stats-hide">
      <td>
        Some Data
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

#### Javascript

```
$(".toggle-stats").click(function() {
    $(".stats-hide, .stats-show").toggle();
});
​
```

Comment: I tried IE8 and FF3.6 under Windows 7 (x86), jQuery 1.4.2 and `toggle(function, function)`. Thanks! I'll try your version now

Comment: I tested these on OSX 10.5 with Chrome 5.0.375.38, Firefox 3.6.3, and Safari 4.0.5. I think multiple links are fine as otherwise you will have to check the link text or some other property to see if stats are currently visible or hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Use a toggle as mentioned in the above post but use a "tbody" instead of a "tr" so that rows can be hidden/shown as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery's [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to alternate between hiding and showing of objects with one link. You wont need to store any variables.